# Pytorch module not found

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, conda, torchvision

I'm using Python 3.6, and trying to use Pytorch. I've uninstalled it using pip3, and re-installed it

```
Hugos-MacBook-Pro-2:project hugokitano$ pip3 install torch 
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.3.1) 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/hugokitano/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from torch) (1.17.2)
```

However, when I try to import torch, the module is not found. I've also tried to install via conda, running

> conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch

and it was successful, installing to

> environment location: /Users/hugokitano/anaconda

However, "import torch" still doesn't work. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is wise to use environments instead of installs packages on your base. Try do the following:

```sh
conda create -n deep7 -c pytorch python=3.7 pytorch torchvision
conda activate deep7
python -c "import torch"
```

We have created an environment with name deep7, we use pytorch channel to install pytorch in Python 3.7. After that we activate the environment and test if the import works. If it did you will see no error.

To use pytorch, you will have to activate your environment:
`conda activate deep7` and to deactivate `conda deactivate`. You can add libraries with `conda install -n deep7 <package name>`

Happy coding

BTW: if you want Python 3.6, do the same, change all the 7 above to 6 :)

Comment: I still get "ImportError: No module named torch" when running `python -c "import torch"`. Any hints?

Comment: Can you print to output of `which python` on unix and `where python` on windows machines?

Comment: Ahhh this fixed it, thanks! I updated the `which python3` to the one living in `anaconda3`, not the usual one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update conda and install it. It weirdly fixed my issue.

```
conda update conda
```

Comment: I get "Package is not installed in prefix."?